# BaseFieldControl and JSLink

Tags: client-side-rendering, rendering

In custom field type class I am overriding JSLink property. So in this case `BaseFieldControl` stop working. Any chance to use this class with overridden JSLink?

**UPDATE:**

```
 public class LookupField : SPFieldLookup
 {
     private const string DefaultJSLink = "~layouts/Test/LookupField.js";
     public override string JSLink
     {
         get
         {
             return string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.JSLink) ? DefaultJSLink : base.JSLink;
         }
         set 
         { 
             base.JSLink = value; }
         }
     } 
}
```

For clearly understanding - first of all I want make some work on server side and after correct UI on client side. Is it possible on EditForm/NewForm?

Comment: Can you please edit question and show how you are overriding the Property?

Comment: @AmalHashim updated

Answer (score 0):

Try below `override`

```
public override string JSLink
{
    get
    {
        if (SPContext.Current != null && SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Invalid)
                return "~layouts/Test/LookupField.js";
         else             
                return string.Empty;                
    }
    set
    {
        base.JSLink = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This working good in case if we want make some magic on server for NewForm template and for example make some UI for View template. But in my case:
#making server logic for NewForm template;
#making good UI on client side for NewForm template;

So if we use your overriding method - we can't make some changes with UI;